# ElasticSearch replica and nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, clustered-index

I am testing now clustering with ElasticSearch and have question about the replicas between the nodes.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot from Head I have 2 indexes.

- movies has 5 shards and 2 replica
- students has 5 shards and 1 replica

Which one is better and which one is faster with 3 active nodes and why?

Comment: just for my understanding; isn't it that, seeing your screenshot, movies has 5 shards but _3_ replica, while students has 5 shards and _2_ repliaca, no?

Answer (score 1):

Costs of having more number of replicas would be

- more storage space required(Obviously)
- less indexing performance

while the advantage from it would be

- better search performance
- better resiliency

Note that even though you have 2 replicas, it does not mean that your cluster can endure 2 nodes going down since all indexing request would fail if only one out of 3 copies of shards is available.(because of `indexing quorum`)

For detailed explanation please refer to [this official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have read a lot of this. My solution will be 2 master, 2 slaves, 8 shards with maybe 2 or 4 replaicas. I need to test the speed and will look forward

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is subjective.

With two replicas, you can handle two of the three machines in your cluster going down, though at the price of writing all the data to every machine.  Read performance should also be higher as the cluster has more nodes from which to request the data.

With one replica, you can only survive the outage of one machine in your cluster, but you'll get a performance boost by writing 2 copies of the data across 3 servers (less IO on each server).

So it comes down to risk and performance.  Hope that helps.

Comment: But this wat the point only for writig. What about searching? Which constilation will be faster for searching?

Comment: But you can have more nodes with 1 replica. My question was if I have more nodes with more replica if the search is faster.

Comment: Yes the search will be faster with more replicas, because replicas are the exact copy of the primary shards and nodes can run queries on the replica nodes. Only difference between primary and replica shard is replica shards does not allow indexing.